# Radio/Toogle Button with validation in the form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple form with radio button group field and selection use toggle button. Validation work normally, except this one.

Use the PHP/Laravel language, but would like to solve with JS (Vanilla), if possible. The intencion is cleaner and generic code in front--end.

**HTML**

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">

        <label>Documento</label>            
        <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="CNH" class="sr-only" required>
                    CNH
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="CPF" class="sr-only" required>
                    CPF
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="ID" class="sr-only" required>
                    Identidade (R.G.)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Selecione o documento que será utilizado.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="numberDocument">Número</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberDocument" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Número não informado!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="clientName">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientName" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Nome do cliente não informado!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

`<input type="radio" name="type" id="document" value="CNH" class="sr-only" required>`

id="document" used in three times

Id Attribute can decalared only once